# xterm launcher on Ubuntu GNOME

Tags: command-line, gnome, launcher

O/S: Ubuntu GNOME 15.04 x64,

I would like to know why xterm/uxterm terminals are not showing up under the applications menu nor found when searched for. My second question is how do I make them show up on search/list of apps.

Xterm is installed (as per the default - /usr/bin/xterm) and I can see .desktop entries in `/usr/share/applications` (namely `debian-uxterm`/`xterm.desktop`. When I rename these .desktop files or move them to `~/.local/share/applications`, the launchers appear. The launcher entries for xterm are alive and well in Ubuntu 14.04 (Unity) without any tinkering being needed.

I can understand the rationale of (appearing to) limit the number of terminals available and it's not affecting my work or anything serious. I would like to know more for my own knowledge rather than anything else.

[search dialogue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mVy41.png)

Comment: maybe _gnome_ does not allow to store `.desktop`s in subdirs ?

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question and clarify what you're actually asking? I'm not sure if you're asking _how_ or _why_.